# Tomcat APR based Apache Tomcat Native Library error

Tags: tomcat, sts-springsourcetoolsuite, apr

I am trying to setup a maven based project in SpringSource tool suite. 
I imported the project and maven imported all the dependencies. I configured tomcat following the guidelines given in [here](http://www.bigsoft.co.uk/blog/index.php/2008/08/10/configuring-eclipse-tomcat-spring).

The project built with no errors. but when I tried to run it, I'm getting the following error. I am new to SprinSource tool suite. Can someone please help me to solve this problem?

```
Feb 17, 2012 1:24:59 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\bin\Perl\bin\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files\ThinkPad\Bluetooth Software\;C:\Program Files\ThinkPad\Bluetooth Software\syswow64;C:\SWTOOLS\ReadyApps;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;.
Feb 17, 2012 1:24:59 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:uix' did not find a matching property.
Feb 17, 2012 1:24:59 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Feb 17, 2012 1:24:59 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1792 ms
Feb 17, 2012 1:24:59 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Feb 17, 2012 1:24:59 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.35
Feb 17, 2012 1:25:00 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(C:\java\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\uix\WEB-INF\lib\geronimo-servlet_3.0_spec-1.0.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
Feb 17, 2012 1:25:01 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(C:\java\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\uix\WEB-INF\lib\tomcat5-servlet-2.4-api-5.5.27.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
Feb 17, 2012 1:25:02 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4149)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4705)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)

Feb 17, 2012 1:25:02 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Skipped installing application listeners due to previous error(s)
Feb 17, 2012 1:25:02 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Feb 17, 2012 1:25:02 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Context [/hiitwide] startup failed due to previous errors
Feb 17, 2012 1:25:02 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Feb 17, 2012 1:25:02 PM org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket init
INFO: JK: ajp13 listening on /0.0.0.0:8009
Feb 17, 2012 1:25:02 PM org.apache.jk.server.JkMain start
INFO: Jk running ID=0 time=0/107  config=null
Feb 17, 2012 1:25:02 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 2563 ms
```

Comment: The error message says it cannot find one of the Spring classes. It certainly has nothing to do with the APR library.

Comment: But I think this spring class error occurs as a result of the APR problem. Because of the APR problem the project is not properly hosted in tomcat and then tomcat tries to find the .class files to load the app. That's when the spring class error comes. I think this is an APR problem

Comment: I have been working with Tomcat for years and I've seen the INFO message about the APR library on each start of Tomcat. So I can tell you for sure that this is not the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

"maven clean" and "maven install" from STS and then restarting the tomcat server.

This work for me